# Get socket peer IPS linux

Tags: linux, sockets, networking

In my linux c++ application I want to write a function hat will check for a giving socket if the socket peer is local. I know how to retrive all the local IPs, but I don't know how to check if the socket peer is from the local IPS list.

any help? with code please!!

10x

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [`getpeername()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xns/getpeername.html) for the *peer* side of the socket.  Use [`getsockname()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xns/getsockname.html) for the *local* side of the socket.  The following snippet will retrieve a sockets local and peer addresses in the Internet domain.  I'll leave it up to you to extend it to handle other types of sockets if you have a need.  I included some rudimentary error checking as a bonus.

```
int
get_addresses(int sd, struct sockaddr_in *local_ptr,
              struct sockaddr_in *peer_ptr)
{
    int rc = -1;
    if (local_ptr == NULL || peer_ptr == NULL) {
        errno = EFAULT;
        return rc;
    }
    if (sd == -1) {
        errno = EBADF;
        return rc;
    }
    if (local_ptr->sin_family != AF_INET || peer_ptr->sin_family != AF_INET) {
        errno = EINVAL;
        return rc;
    }

    rc = getsockname(sd, (struct sockaddr*)local_ptr,
                     sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    if (rc == 0) {
        rc = getpeername(sd, (struct sockaddr*)local_ptr,
                         sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
        if (rc < 0) {
            if (errno == ENOTCONN) {
                /* socket is not connected so zero out the peer side */
                peer_ptr->sin_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
                peer_ptr->sin_family = AF_INET;
                peer_ptr->sin_port = 0;
                peer_ptr->sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_NONE;
                rc = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return rc;
}
```

Comment: does getpeername retrive all the peer adrress (all NICs addres in peer)?

Comment: @gin No, just the addr that your end is connected to.

Comment: which system call can retrive ALL the peer's addresses?

Comment: A socket is a connection between two IP endpoints (i.e., protocol, IP address, and port).  This is the only information available from the socket.  There is no system call to enumerate the available network interfaces and bindings on the remote system.